# jQuery select all children

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, local-storage, css-selectors

I've built a small application for a user to request machines to be built. I do this by saving the specifics into localStorage when a form is submitted, and then looping through the storage variables to display a detail look of the request.. The display portion of this loops through local storage and appends a `ul` with an `li` input for each of the pieces of info that pertain to each particular machine.

Below is a rough example of what my display ends up looking like right before they submit. I need to select the value of each `input`, and use it within a `localStorage.Removeitem('all machine 1 input values go here');` I apologize for the rough code, i'm new to most of this.

```
<ul name="machine-1">
    <li><input type="button" value="Del"></li>
    <li><input value="name1"></li>
    <li><input value="number1"></li>
</ul>

<ul name="machine-2">
    <li><input type="button" value="Del"></li>
    <li><input value="name2"></li>
    <li><input value="number2"></li>
</ul>
```

Heres the portion of my loop that builds the lists.

```
$("#theRequest").append('<ul id="machine-'+ machinec +'"><li style="border:none;margin-left:0em;padding-right:0em;"><input class="delete" type="button" id="del-'
    + machinec +'" value="Del"></li><li>'
    + '</li><li style="border:none;margin-left:0em;padding-right:0em;"><input class="edit" type="hidden" value="Edit"></li>'
    + '</li><li><input style="width:35px;" disabled type="text" value="'
    + nomember + '"></li><li><input style="width:20px;" disabled type="text" value="'
    + ecmpny + '"></li><li><input style="width:20px;" disabled type="text" value="'
    + estore + '"></li><li><input style="width:60px;" disabled type="text" value="'
    + hmachineType + '"></li><li><input disabled type="text" value="'
    + efullname + '"></li><li><input disabled type="text" value="'
    + etitle + '"></li><li><input disabled type="hidden" value="'
    + hrequested + '"></li><li><input disabled type="hidden" value="'
    + eemail + '</li></ul>');
```

Here is my guess at how to 'remove' the particular machine and clear it out of localStorage. I'm basically not selecting it right, and if i were, I still think it would only select one of the grandchildrens values?

```
// Delete a Machine
$('.delete').click(function() {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this item?')) {
        var parent = $(this).parents('ul');
        var grandchildren = parent.children().children();
        parent.hide();
        inputName = grandchildren.attr('value');
        localStorage.removeItem(inputName);                     
    }                           
    else {}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this

```
// Delete a Machine
$('.delete').click(function() {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this item?')) {
        var parent = $(this).parents('ul').eq(0);  // just in case you have more than one ul ancestor
        parent.hide();
        parent.find('input').each(function() {
            localStorage.removeItem($(this).attr('value'));
        });                    
    }
});
```

By the way, if you're using jQuery 1.7 or later, you could use `$('.delete').on("click", function() {`